# design a print funtion for debug mode

Tags: python

I am trying to design a print function `dprint` for debugging use. Specifically, this is what I want to achieve:

```
def func1(a,b,debug=0):
    if debug:
        print(Something) # print something if debug mode
```

below is how I design the `dprint`

```
def func2(a,b,debug=0):
    def dprint(*args):  
        if debug:
            print(*args)  # using the local variable `debug` to detect whether is under debug mood
    dprint(Something) # print something if debug mode
```

`func2` can work but is not nice since I need to insert the `dprint` function into every other function. I wonder if there is a more decent way to achieve this `dprint` function.

Comment: why dont you use python logging module?

Comment: I can't understand your code... Why `func2`, `func1` and `dprint`? And yes, why aren't you using the built-in functionality of [`logging`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html)? i.e. [`logger.debug`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a global variable `debug` instead of a parameter and make `dprint` its own function.

```py
debug = True
def dpring(*args, **kwargs):
    if debug:
        print(*args, **kwargs)

def func2(a, b):
    dprint(Somthing)
# OR
def func2(a, b, debug_=0):
    global debug # not necesary but IMO it makes the code more readable
    debug = bool(debug_)
    dprint(Something)
```

Comment: As in the question, what's the purpose of `func1` and `func2`? What's wrong with just `dprint`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the decorator:

```
def dprint(func):
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('debug',0) == 1:
            print('Something')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _f
    
@dprint    
def f(a, b, debug=0):
    print(a, b)
```

In this case you only need to add a `@dprint` on all the functions you want this feature.

Comment: I feel he only wants to have a function that prints to show this function is running in debug mode.

Comment: Oh well the question is not very clear so that might be the case. I will delete my comments and let OP judge

Comment: yes I think this is how he plans to use it...in his post he said he was going to add this function in all the functions with a debug kwarg

Comment: I don't see any mentioning for a debug `kwarg` in the question...

Comment: A nice addition can be to make the debug message an argument to the decorator so each function can have a different message